# How to compare two different extension files in php?

Tags: php

I've two different files, say, **pdf** and **jpeg** extension files. I need to compare these two files. If it is **pdf** I need to send this to **attachments** folder if not to **image** folder. How can I achieve this in *php*. Is there a way to ***compare***? if so how?.. Can anyone give an idea for this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Compare in what way? You already know the files have different content.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried? Please post up some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its basic.

```
<?php    
$ext= explode(".",$filename); // explode filename by "."
$extension= $ext[1];// get extension. 
if($extension=="pdf")
{
 // do something
}
elseif($extension=="jpg" ||$extension=="png"..... ) 
{
// do something
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

```
<?php
$file1 = pathinfo('file.pdf');
$file2 = pathinfo('file.jpg');

echo $file1['extension']; // will output pdf
echo $file2['extension']; // will output jpg
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$file1 = pathinfo($file1Path);
$file2 = pathinfo($file2Path);

if($file1['extension'] === $file2['extension']) {
  //The extensions are the same.
}

if($file1['extension'] === 'pdf') {
  //extensions is PDF and so on
}
```

Comment: @Ares ur bad, OP accepted some elses answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
$fileExt = explode('.','yourFileWithExtension');
if($fileExt[1] == 'pdf') {
   //move to attachments folder
} else {
  // some other folder
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$file_extension = pathinfo("example.pdf", PATHINFO_EXTENSION)
if ($file_extension == "jpg") {
    your code here to send to image folder
} else if ($file_extension == "pdf") {
    your code here to send to attachments folder
}
```